# How to get all objects inside an array JSON in a C# controller

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, deserialization

How do I retrieve all of the [names] that are part of the object called [items] in this JSON scenario below in C# ?

I am using a shopping cart api and want to show the customer all of the items listed off that were part of the order once they get to the thank you page. The parent object I am looking at in the api is called **items** and it has child object data such as price of each item, name of each item and product image of each item etc.....

In my controller I was doing this below when I only needed to retrieve simple info like the order only has 1 invoiceNumber, 1 payment method, 1 shipping method, 1 promo code etc.. This code below works and gets me that data in that simple scenario below.

```
 using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            var obj = JObject.Parse(result);

            
            //Order Info
            string invoiceNumber = (string)obj["invoiceNumber"];
            string email = (string)obj["email"];
            string paymentMethod = (string)obj["paymentMethod"];
            string shippingMethod = (string)obj["shippingMethod"];

            //Discount info
            string amountSaved = (string)obj["discounts"][0]["amountSaved"];
            string promoCode = (string)obj["discounts"][0]["code"];
```

But now I need to tap into an object called [items] (the data for the items that were part of the order) that is going to have many **names** of items depending on the number of individual items that were part of the customer order. This is what I attempted but then realized that it would only return one record based on what number I used inside the brackets.

```
string items = (string)obj["items"][0]["name"]; //This returned the product at index 0
string items = (string)obj["items"][1]["name"]; //This returned the product at index 1
string items = (string)obj["items"][2]["name"]; //This returned the product at index 2
```

How do I write the syntax so that I can grab ALL of the **name** objects that currently reside in the **item** object for exaple? I know it has something to do with deserialize objects and list but I do not know the syntax and how to approach.

Any suggestions on how I can get this done?

Comment: The main gist would be to create a strongly typed object that represents the JSON schema of the response back. This way instead of parsing it as an `object`, you can _deserialize_ it into that representation. Once you've done that, you are free to act and operate on it. It's important that you match the types accordingly, such as: `items` property seems to be a _collection_ of individual items that were purchased where one property you are interested in would be the _name_ - once it's a collection, you can enumerate over each one to retrieve relevant information such as it's name, etc.

Comment: Since `obj["items"]` is already an indexed collection, do foreach upon it or `.Select(o => o["name"])` maybe? But yeah, if the object structure is confirmed, then Anthony Forloney's approach is more reasonable, more benefits such like that instead of calling properties through string which will fail if there's ever a typo, you can then make sure what properties are there in the structure.

Comment: Ok I see, so I have now created a class with the properties I want to retrieve that represents the JSON schema data. But how do I reference that class in the call I am going to make when returning the list of items properties that I want.

Like if I write this string items = (string)obj["items"]; how do I bring the class into play?

Comment: @CodeQuest Can you show us your `result` JSON string?

Comment: @RahulSharma do you mean this:

[
  {  
    "name": "prod1",
    "price": "12.99",
    "quantity": "4"
  },
  {
    "name": "prod2",
    "price": "17.65",
    "quantity": "1"
  }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simpliest way

```
List<string> names = obj["items"].Select(x => (string) x["name"] ).ToList();
```

test

```
Console.WriteLine( string.Join(",",names)); // prod1,prod2
```

more complicated way is to create a c# class and deserialize data. But in this case you will be able to use Linq for queries and search

```
 List<Item>  items = obj["items"].Select(x => x.ToObject<Item>()).ToList()

public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

result (in json format)

```
[
  {
    "name": "prod1",
    "price": 12.99,
    "quantity": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "prod2",
    "price": 17.65,
    "quantity": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft json package to convert an object into JSON array.
Refer below link

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm